# Position div on top of nav using CSS

Tags: html, css

I have an issue when trying to position a logo in front of/on top of a navigation bar (with dropdown links). My current CSS and HTML is below, however I am open to alternative suggestions, and any and all help appreciated. I want the logo to appear on the far right hand side of the nav bar:

[image]

I want to have the nav bar move up so it's halfway up the placeholder logo. Unfortunately I'm not skilled in the use of `position:` or `top:` and `bottom:`

CSS:

```
.logo
{
position:relative;
z-index: 2;
width: 100%;
height:200px;
text-align:right;
}

#nav
{
z-index: 1;
border:0;
background-color:#FFEE00;
list-style:none;
padding-right: 300px; /* the width of the logo, so logo doesn't obscure text on smaller screens/re-sized windows */
text-align:left;
font-family:Inky,"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
font-size:18px;
}

#nav li
{
position:relative;
display:inline;
}

#nav a
{
display:inline-block;
padding:10px;
}

#nav ul
{
position:absolute;
left:-9999px;
margin:0;
padding:0;
text-align:left;
}

#nav ul li
{
display:block;
background-color:#fff;
}

#nav li:hover ul
{
left:0;
}

#nav li:hover a
{
text-decoration:underline;
background:#FFEE00;
}

#nav li:hover ul a
{
text-decoration:none;
background:none;
}

#nav li:hover ul a:hover
{
text-decoration:underline;
background:#f1f1f1;
}

#nav ul a
{
white-space:nowrap;
display:block;
border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;
}

#nav a
{
color:#000;
text-decoration:none;
font-weight:lighter;
}

#nav a:hover
{
text-decoration:underline;
background:#f1f1f1;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="logo">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/300x200" alt="logo" height="200" width="300">
        </div>


        <ul id="nav">
            <li><a href="/">HOME</a></li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">CLUBS ></a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Coming soon!</a></li>                       
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">SHOWS ></a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Coming soon!</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">WORKSHOPS ></a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Coming soon!</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">KIDS ></a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Coming soon!</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">TESTIMONIALS</a>
            </li>                               
            <li>
                <a href="#">NEWS</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">CONTACT US ></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I would recommend you making a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) for us :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my experience using margin usually do the trick

```
 .logo
 {
 position:relative;
 z-index: 2;
 width: 100%;
 height:200px;
 text-align:right;
 margin-right: 0;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-bottom: -140px; //Tho i would fine tune this if i were you

 //Or if you wish margin: 0px 0px -140px auto (margin: top right bottom left)
 }
```

Comment: Thanks! This is a possible winner, but note that I had to remove position:relative for my dropdown links to work.

Comment: This appears to be the one. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Adding:

```
position: relative;
top: -140px;
```

to `#nav` seems to do it.

Comment: Thanks, but that then loses the dropdown links from the nav bar. I did attempt this method. Something to do with the #nav li position:relative ?

Answer (score 0):

By "halfway up the placeholder logo" I understand you want the nav bar at the middle (vertical) of the logo. You will have to displace your logo as `position:absolute`, and set the `ul` top.

Try adding this css:

```
.logo img
{
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 2;
}

.logo ul
{
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: This didn't change anything at all - maybe I missed something.